# Make non-member view activity report on Private chatter groups

Tags: chatter

We have a group for community moderators and need to provide them access to view the reports for private groups' activities (likes count, comments count etc.,). Currently, in the report they can see only the private groups of which they are member of but they need to view the data for all the private groups in the community.
We don't want to give **View all data** access to them.

1. I figured the chatter groups object is **CollaborationGroup.obj** which shows only developer console, so I am not able to create a permission set or profile and provide full access to that object.
   So is there any other way we can achieve this?